# CMattitude in JavaScript for iOS motion events?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, core-motion

Are you able to use Apple's **CMAttitude** in JavaScript, or can you only access it through a native app?

I'm building a web app that uses the gyroscope to navigate a large flat image. As you rotate the device the viewfinder moves as if it is your eye. I successfully used **ondeviceorientation** to create a prototype, but am seeing that CMAttitude - and CMMotion in general - may be a better way to go.

If it is possible, could you please provide me with a link to either a demo or explanation.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access it through a native app.

First thought -

I would check out Oblong's g-speak SDK and its notion of a "pointer", which in their idiom means a pointing device. I've used it a tiny bit and it is easy to use and works very well. See: http://oblong.com/

Second thought -

If you wanted you could write a binding for PhoneGap (now Apache Cordova) to provide the data. It appears that Cordova only provides access to accelerometer data:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer

If you were going to build that binding:

Core Motion uses a sensor fusion algorithm to combine the outputs of the gyroscope, the accelerometer, and the magnetometer into a `CMDeviceMotion`.

You can get a `CMAttitude` from the `CMDeviceMotion` to get information about the device's orientation relative to some reference orientation, for example `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical`.